# Interpreting the meaning of the norm of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

Given is the definition $$C^0([a, b]): ||f|| = \sqrt{|f|} = \sqrt{<f|f>} = \sqrt{\int_a^b{f(x)^2dx} }$$

As an example, let's assume that $f(x) = x,  x \in [0, 1]$. Therefore

$$||f|| = \sqrt{\int_0^1{x^2dx}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} = 0.577$$

From my understanding, in this case the norm signifies the maximum value of the distance of $f$ to 0 for the given interval, but by looking at the graph of $f(x)$ you'd easily see that it's 1 and not 0.577. So what exactly does the norm mean in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the maximum, but the average squared distance from $f$ to $0$

Comment: @caverac So what exactly is the point if having the average distance between two functions? I got another problem that wants me to calculate the distance between two functions, but I'm not quiet understanding why I'd want the average and, let's say, not the minimum or maximum distance? Thanks!

Comment: There are several notions of distance between functions. The maximum distance makes sense for continuous bounded functions, but what if your functions are not bounded? How would you make sense of the distance between $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ in the interval 0 to 1 for example?

Comment: @Paul Ah alright, gotcha. So in this case it's kind of useless to calculate the average distance, though that apparently is the task that was given.

Comment: My example was not a good one as neither function has an $L^2$ norn in 0 to 1, but you get the idea!  The $L^2$ norm might also have a physical meaning - in electrical science it is the average power in a signal so 'close' in this norm means close in average power.

Comment: @Paul Well, I expect there to be a deeper physical meaning at some point as this topic was discussed in my first month as an undergrad engineering student. So thanks for already giving me an example for a real application!